# Iteratively apply range-v3 views::filter on a container

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20, range-v3

In the `for` loop in the following code snippet I'm trying to apply `views::filter`. But it results in type miss match and assignment error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{
    int limit =100;
    std::vector<int> numbers(100);
    std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 1);
    auto results = numbers | ranges::views::filter([](int n) {return n != 1; });
                           
    int sqrt_limit = std::sqrt(limit);
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt_limit; i++)
    {
        results = results | ranges::views::filter([i](int n) {return n == i
            || n % i != 0; });
    }
}
```

> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'ranges::filter_viewranges::filter_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,Arg>,main::<lambda_2>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

So basically how can I apply `views::filter` on `numbers` ,assign the result in `results` , then apply `views::filter` on `results` and then again assign the result in `results`?

```
std::vector<int> numbers(100);
std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 1);
auto results = numbers | ranges::views::filter([](int n) {return n != 1; });
results = results | ranges::views::filter([i](int n) {return n == 2
        || n % 2 != 0; });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the return type of `results | ranges::views::filter` is different from `results`, so you cannot assign it to `results`.

The alternative is to use `ranges::to` to convert each result into a `vector` and assign it to the previous result:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(100);
std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 1);
auto results = numbers
             | ranges::views::filter([](int n) {return n != 1; })
             | ranges::to_vector;
results = results
        | ranges::views::filter([](int n) {return n == 2|| n % 2 != 0; })
        | ranges::to_vector;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/jPeq4YPes)

Comment: Thank you . I didn't know about ranges::to<> .

Answer (score 1):

`views::filter` returns a different type than the range type passed in. You could apply `ranges::to` to create a vector after you filter each time, but this is going to be expensive. For this problem, i.e. generating primes using a sieve, it makes sense to use an eager algorithm.

The first filter you've applied is unnecessary; just start the `iota` at 2, since that's the first prime.

```
auto results = numbers;
```

Then while there are still primes to sieve

```
auto end = std::end(results);
for (auto begin = std::begin(results); begin != end; begin++)
    end = std::remove_if(begin + 1, end,        // *begin is prime by definition, so skip it
                         [i = *begin](int n) {
                            return n % i == 0;  // remove multiples of the prime 
                            });

// erase all the composite numbers
results.erase(end, std::end(results));
```

The above loop is doing a filter as well, but using `remove`, so the condition has to be negated. Also, since the prime itself is skipped, the lambda doesn't need to check if `n == i`.

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjcb14znT)